# Two mouse pointers

Tags: display, mouse, 20.04

For some odd reason, the mouse pointer from when you login doesn't disappear. So I get two mouse pointers, one which just sits there, seemingly frozen

This is annoying because it distracts you and it can't be removed.

Any possible fixes?